# Portable Chrome as different process than locally installed Chrome?

Tags: java, google-chrome, process

I have Java app, that runs local embedded jetty, with static files and rest endpoints. I would like to ship it with portable chrome and run browser (to render html/js (UI)) from my app. When browser terminates, I need to shutdown jetty and app.
I am spawning new process via

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("path to chrome with parameters etc")
```

and then

```
p.waitFor();
```

to hang my wait thread until browser is closed and it works OK.

Problem starts, when user has his own chrome instance run locally. (I think) My portable chrome process "connects" to main chrome process, and `p.waitFor()` method hangs until I close both chrome instances. Is this possible to run portable chrome as other, independent system process?
I tried:

```
--disable-plugins --disable-background-mode --incognito --app="link" --user-data-dir="temp dir"
```

Problem exists on windows.

When I run process in Ubuntu:

```
String userDataDirFixed = " --user-data-dir=${HOME}/.gcp/";
                browserProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=" + uri.toString() + SUFFIX + userDataDirFixed);
```

It works ok, even now, when I am using my chrome browser.
Maybe some ideas please? :)